# In light of the user base, are there any changes SO should make?

Tags: discussion

I was reading [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) of which, one of the answers referenced [this site](https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?qcLocale=en_US). A *huge* amount of traffic to SO is **during weekdays and the school year**.

Via the second link:
[image: SO unique visitors per weeks]

The dips and canyons (deep dips) are weekends/vacations (read: time that students don't use SO).

Since a significant amount of traffic is coming from students, are there any changes SO should make to accommodate them?

Comment: The reason so many students use stack is because it became known as one of the best resources (since it has high quality standard). If we accommodate these students, the quality will likely drop, driving traffic away. But what EXACTLY are the changes you think should be done?

Comment: Well weekends are times when people would be off work and not on the site. I would also wager that the vacation dips will line up with periods that a lot of people tend to take time off.

Comment: Those deep dives look more like people taking Christmas break to me.

Comment: Strangely, weekends and vacations are also times when professional programmers don't work.

Comment: In regards to your question - what changes do you think would accommodate students more? I don't understand the problem you are trying to tell us about.

Comment: @Oded Weekends and holiday weekends, yes.  But the large trend down during the summer, when school is off, is the one notable deviation, and it *is* a trend that we see on the trendline.

Comment: @Servy - sure. Schools, colleges and universities. But also families of said school children - part of the families would be professional programmers.

Comment: @Oded: Seems like a case for closing as unclear. I have an *idea* what the OP could be implying, but it's simply my own conjecture.

Comment: @BoltClock to be fair it IS a discussion, so I guess the OP wants us to figure out the changes needed? (not defending what he thinks should be done, just saying why it may not be as unclear as if it was a Feature Request)

Comment: @Oded You think that a significant percentage of that down trend during the summer is professional programmers that take the whole summer off because their kids are out of school?  I'm sure that there are some number of people doing that, and perhaps some professional teachers, but I wouldn't expect there to be enough of those users to affect the curve to any notable degree.  They're likely insignificant in comparison to the number of students.

Comment: The, "I'm new to programming, where do I start?"  questions could be gathered into a common area and categorized, stuff like, "How to set up an IDE", "How to write Hello World", "How to  write a socket". SO aims to be a "a library of detailed answers to every question about programming." (via http://stackoverflow.com/tour). A big pile of books != a library.

Comment: @Servy - I'm saying they also factor in. I am sure a large drop is mostly students - but not just them. Regardless - I still have no idea what the OP wants to discuss (accommodate students, how, in what manner?).

Comment: @FuriousFolder There are already lots of places that do that already.  In the case of students, that you're trying to cater to, that would be what their teachers/textbooks are for.

Comment: A free pizza for answering a student question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've always thought that we should have more guidance for educators on the value that Stack Overflow can have for coursework. Students are sometimes heavily penalized for using the site, and I think that's silly, because professional programmers use it every day. It's not just Stack Overflow, many students can't use *any* resource that actual programmers use.

Coursework should have some (more) focus on *how to ask for help when you don't know how to solve a problem*, and that should begin in the classroom, but why should those skills be confined *to* a classroom? That's always baffled me.

In summary, I think we could do a better job with outreach to teachers to help them help their students to make the most out of resourcefulness, letting go of the idea that pedagogy can only flourish in isolation. We should show them how they can use Stack Overflow as a tool to teach, instead of monitor for evidence of homework.

tl;dr - I think we do a fine job with students. It's their teachers we really need to be reaching.

Comment: I can say that reaching out to teachers has had an impact. I've talked to professors when it was clear that students were copying and pasting lesson assignments from their class, and several of them now incorporate lessons on what's appropriate to post here in the first lecture of a class. I know Robert and Bill had said something similar about other teachers they'd contacted. People assume that all computer science educators would know about the site, its conventions, and the way students sometimes try to use it to cheat, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @BradLarson I've done the same. I think putting all of that experience together in one useful place might be a pretty good idea. As a programmer you're going to need to learn how to ask for help from other programmers, that's a skill as essential as learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: I don't want to be pedantic, but are you sure you mean pedantry?

Comment: @BillWoodger I did, it was a conscious choice of wording and I'm aware that it doesn't simply imply teaching. I also answered hundreds of questions tagged [homework] before we deprecated the tag.

Comment: Perhaps I need to look at my American dictionary when I get home then. I'll keep trying to make sense of that paragraph in the mean time.

Comment: Even looking at Webster's online, I still don't get it. The most positive aspect I can find is a pedant being "a formalist or precisionist in teaching "., or "one who makes a show of knowledge" whereas I think most commonly, if asked to define, people would think of "one who is unimaginative or who unduly emphasizes minutiae in the presentation or use of knowledge". Just saying. A bit pedantically.

Comment: Looks like an autocorrect mishap involving "pedagogy".

Comment: Fine, me and my sense of humor will go have a bagel. My humor isn't lost on bagels, they always laugh at me.

Comment: Humor? Never used it, it doesn't seem to be fun...

Answer (score 8):

Speaking as a user that joined while I was in my last semester of college, I can say that Stack Overflow has already done *quite a lot* to accommodate students.  However, there's quite a lot that Stack Overflow *shouldn't* do to accommodate students, too.

First, the question quality of students or beginners in programming leaves much to be desired.  The average student that made use of Stack Overflow while I was in college believed that they could just post their assignment and have someone complete it for them.  There's no forgiveness or leniency as far as I'm concerned for someone that decides, "I'm going to dump this homework assignment here; someone may help me out later."

Next, there are the "help me I'm stuck" style of problems.  I don't doubt that we've all been stuck on something we're working on, but there is very little that Stack Overflow can do to help a student truly get *un*stuck.  Consider that now I'm in my third year of professional development, and I have ways of solving particular problems.  I know that my solutions wouldn't necessarily translate well to a rookie looking to get a hint on how to simply overcome their *problem*.  Even if they did, though, how much value does one get from a question that states, "I don't know how this works, I got this far but I'm stuck, could you help?"- especially when that is code that would never make its way into production?

I think that we're doing alright as it is.  We've definitely become stricter about our question quality, so we don't have to worry as much about the two above scenarios.  In essence, so long as a student is able to ask a question that can survive on Stack Overflow, we've done pretty much all we need to.

Answer (score 6):

Given that such a large portion of the SO user base is *already* students, it would seem that we *already* accommodate them rather well.

The mission of SO is to create a repository of useful questions and answers.  As the evidence has shown, that is useful for both students and non-students alike.

Comment: Actually, the mission of SO is " to build a **library** of detailed answers to every question about programming." Via http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @FuriousFolder In creating a one sentence description of the site for people who have never actually seen it, some subtitles just can't be accounted for.  If you continue to read on, both there, and elsewhere, you'll see that that, while a passable summary to a brand new user, is not an entirely accurate description of why the site exists, or what its core values are.  The site has made it very clear, in the tour an elsewhere, that *every* programming question isn't on topic on SO, for example.