# Recent spike in the pending Low Quality Reviews count for SO main?

Tags: support, flags

For the past several months the flag count has been steadily in the 100 to 300 count range. However, recently I have been noticing that it is breaking into the 4 digit range, reaching 1150 just now. I began to take notice only a few days ago when it was in the 900s.

The specific queue which seems to be taking the brunt of this increase is the Low Quality Posts queue.

Is this a temporary increase due to some metric changing in triage, or reviews in general?

What changed that resulted in the increase in the flag count, and is the increase going to be temporary or are we seeing a trend of a growing queue number of flags?

Comment: I'd guess it has less to do with inflow into the queue than with its outflow. More people [taking 1->4 train](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077), fewer reviewers.

Comment: Review queue counts and flag counts are two very different things.

Comment: How do you know how many flags mods have? O_O

Comment: I think the [increased LA threshold](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266696/can-we-raise-the-bar-for-reputation-for-late-answers-to-bypass-the-review-queue) had an unforeseen side effect: more VLQ/NAA flags from late answers (most of them justified; I still support that change). And since LQP was already having trouble staying caught up, even a fairly small but persistent increase had a nasty effect long-term.

Comment: @NormalHuman If that is true, should the inflow not go down? I used to flag things, now I don't care anymore because the shit just keeps piling up. What gives?

Comment: @JustAnotherDotNetDev Many flags are automatic, based on the length of posts, and possibly on the keywords associated with NAAs.

Comment: @NormalHuman TMYK

Comment: Also, the LQRQ is slooooowwwwwwwwwwww.......

Comment: @NormalHuman Guilty as charged. :<

Comment: What is the flag count? New flags per day? New flags per hour? Total stock of flag that has not been handled?

Comment: @Anders: The last of those. 10k users get a count in the topbar that covers nearly all review tasks that have yet to be processed. (It doesn't include close votes here on SO, and it doesn't include diamond-only reviews.)

Comment: The dysfunctional review audits certainly add to this. Those are constantly banning people who are trying to help & are doing so correctly. Why are you surprised that the crap starts piling up? The guy who designed the low quality review audits should be given unlimited reviews and then get tasked of keeping the queue clear.

Comment: Looks like a lot of short answers are being robo-flagged going back from 2008. Many ending in *rhetorical* questions, which are also perfectly good answers. Argh.

Comment: @Tim Post: "It doesn't matter how useful an answer is. If it ends in a question mark, *it must go.*"

Comment: @BoltClock I really hope that last comment was intended as sarcasm/irony :-(

Comment: I think why you're seeing this over the last week or so is that multiple prolific elected moderators have had personal or work matters that have drawn them away from the site at the same time. The flag queue has grown as a result. It should ease back down when people return.

Comment: @BradLarson - So this is just part of the ebb and flow of the queue then? If there was no change and that is the case, do you mind answering this so I can mark that as accepted so this is "resolved" so to speak.

Comment: @TravisJ - I think so, but there could be other factors. I seems like we've been declining a higher percentage of "not an answer" and "very low quality" flags lately, apparently from some poorly-run queries some people have been running.

Comment: @Sobrique we've already got a lot of problem from people badgewhoring in the review queue.  Making that worse by offering rep would be two very large steps back.

Comment: End of quarter/semester and holiday for school means finals and tests and a avalanche of help vampires that want to go on holiday and not have to explain why they are failing to their parents.

Comment: I personally have a feeling that the annual influx of students (much like a USENET September, eh?) is not helping things. "need help with homewrk. give me da codez?? plz!!"

Comment: @JimGarrison: Yes; note the use of quotation marks.

Comment: @JasonMc92 A few months ago I did an analysis on SO's hits from its conception to current day, with weekly granularity and found that during "summer" months (May-August) SO's average hits were ~20% lower.

Comment: @FuriousFolder, I'm curious then, is there also a spike in September, October and January? (I'm noticing that the homework influx is only just starting to die down.)

Comment: @JasonMc92 Yep. The spike from December->January is pretty huge, but that's likely due to professionals spending time with their families. For reference, here's my original question: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302527/in-light-of-the-user-base-are-there-any-changes-so-should-make

And the site I used: https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com?qcLocale=en_US#trafficCard