# Autumn 2015 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-election

The Fall 2015 Community Moderator Election is now underway! It's been a few years since we've run two elections in a single year, but folks have cried out for more active moderators and so here we go!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the [official election page](https://stackoverflow.com/election) for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: @Shog9 - Its not very clear how you nominate yourself?  I click on the election page only to be told to "brave it out and nominate yourself" from here I see no way to "nominate myself".

Comment: And I need to read more often: You need all of the following badges to nominate yourself as a candidate: Strunk & White, Civic Duty, Deputy, and Convention

Comment: @Braiam I know now :|

Comment: Can the query be changed to state what badge I may be missing?  I hate having to go look through my badges...

Comment: @JonH And badges halt your claim that you nominate yourself. Better luck next election!

Comment: @Kendra - You got me...well at least I predicted there would be nominations!

Comment: @JonH A quick glance at your badges says you're missing Deputy, btw. :) I see the other three right away in the first column of yours when sorted by class.

Comment: Yep I just noticed that too.  Looks like I need to start raising them flags more often.

Comment: Mmm... this is weird, I have all the badges yet I don't see the nominate myself button, maybe they forgot the reputation privileges too?

Comment: @Braiam You have to have at least 3k to nominate yourself.

Comment: @Undo yep, it was on the side bar, grrrrrr!

Comment: @JonH As a side effect, more flags -> more frequent elections -> more chances for you to win.

Comment: That whole page needs to be redesigned.

Comment: Why does http://stackoverflow.com/election/0 say “There are no active community moderator elections at the moment.”?

Comment: @Xufox Also I've found this little nuance :-) [Check this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292708/259412).

Comment: @Arjun why remove the tags?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this election is over, and the post is no longer relevant.

Comment: @Mureinik The general consensus seems to be to leave these posts open (see all the others).