# Will Stack Overflow moderators also moderate Documentation?

Tags: support, moderators, moderator-election, documentation

With the upcoming [documentation expansion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303865/465378), it has been hinted at that the two services will be more integrated than separate Stack Exchange sites. For example, the announcement mentions that reputation will be shared.

> You'll get reputation for peer-reviewed contributions to Documentation. Peer review may take the form of citations, suggested edit reviews, explicit voting, or a combination of all three. **Reputation you earn from Documentation will be added to the existing Q&A reputation; there won't be two separate numbers.** Obviously, we're still working out lots of the details.

<sup>(Emphasis mine.)</sup>

With this in mind, will Stack Overflow moderators also assume a moderation role on Documentation? If so, given that at the time of this writing a [new moderator election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309752/465378) is about to begin, should this factor be considered when voting on candidates?

Comment: [From the "Your Questions Answered" post,](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306213/warlords-of-documentation-your-questions-answered?lq=1#comment248103_306219) it looks like it's currently planned to be the SO mods.

Comment: @Kendra Aha, good find! I looked through that post but didn't scour the comments. If you want to quote that and post it as an answer, it would probably be a good one.

Comment: Chris beat me to it. :) His answer is good enough, in my mind.

Comment: @AnnaLear errr - what's with the "Mean Girls" video link as the edit reason? :p

Comment: @JonClements You have to take it in context with the changes diff. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear Hmph! You think you can stop the ***will of the people?!*** ;)

Comment: I came here hoping to learn your grand plan to use mods + docs to finally eliminate those pesky "null reference exception" questions. Am so disappointed.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As far as I understand, the existing Stack Overflow moderators will also be moderators of the Documentation <s>expansion pack</s> site as well. At least initially.

It doesn't make sense to appoint/elect new moderators for something that it still, at this stage, an experiment. In the initial stages the existing moderator team, with the back up of the community managers and developers, can probably handle the extra work load (or at least will be able to once the new <s>victims</s> moderators have been <s>sacrificed</s> elected).

In the longer term, should the site take off it may become necessary to elect dedicated documentation moderators, but it seems a little premature to be discussing that now.

Comment: Sounds about right. Note that Documentation isn't a separate *site*. The private beta for it will be, but eventually docs will be integrated into Stack Overflow, so moderator privileges on SO will pass on to the docs section. As for whether or not we'll need more granular privilege levels... time will tell.

Answer (score 18):

ChrisF covered the current plans for Documentation moderation, but as for your last question...

> If so, given that at the time of this writing a new moderator election is about to begin, should this factor be considered when voting on candidates?

I don't think so. There's no way to tell exactly what moderating Documentation is going to be like, what practical needs are going to be in play, and so on. For the purposes of the election, I'd advise ignoring any upcoming features/changes entirely at this stage.