# How to get pending flags looked at, and the corresponding question closed?

Tags: discussion, flags, vote-to-close

2 weeks ago, I flagged the question [VHDL : Why my outputs in FSM for SPI interface are becoming 'X red' whenever they shall be written with outputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56314116/vhdl-why-my-outputs-in-fsm-for-spi-interface-are-becoming-x-red-whenever-the) as useless (no code provided, solved by the author who didn't really post how either).
But it's still in my pending flags.
I read some of the meta questions about pending flags, like some on how useless it is to flag very old questions, as nobody will ever see the flag, but in this case I raised the flag only 2 days after the question was "sent".
Would it ever be seen without this meta question, or would it also have been a wasted flag?
If so, could there be a system created to actually clean up older useless posts?

Comment: There simply aren't enough people willing to evaluate and close questions that aren't on topic.  As such, a large percentage of flags on the topic won't get evaluated, because there just aren't enough people to do so.  And not just for very old posts.

Comment: Closing a question is useful to prevent answers that are mere guesses from getting added.  Not this question's problem and that is not unusual at all in a small community that supports a highly specialized tag.  Also the problem with flags, reviewers have no real shot at being helpful.  Just let the automatic cleanup (aka Roomba) take care of it, a single downvote is enough.

Comment: Well, normally, voting fraud is a chronic problem.  I halped.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flag has been active for months](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266842/flag-has-been-active-for-months) or [Why do my diamond moderator flags take such a variable amount of time to handle?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309628/why-do-my-diamond-moderator-flags-take-such-a-variable-amount-of-time-to-handle?rq=1)

Comment: There are some people who are intentionally on strike from reviewing, so that might be making it harder for the flags to get evaluated: [Declaring a Review strike until efficiency improvements are implemented](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385023/7795130)

Comment: Close flags largely just age away and have for a long time.

Comment: Now another user has close-voted with the same close reason as your flag, validating it as "helpful" (even though it's not closed yet)

Comment: *"useless it is to flag very old questions, as nobody will ever see the flag"* This is wrong. Flags are not prioritized based on the age of the question.

Comment: @DavyM There has never been a time in the entire history of the site's existence where reviewers have kept up with the number of questions needing closure.  That a handful of people have gone on strike recently hasn't made this some new thing.

Comment: @CodyGray It's not the only factor, but unless it's been changed at some point the age of the post is one of the factors the close vote review queue incorporates in determining which post to give to a given reviewer, so *indirectly* post age affects how likely a flag is to be actually reviewed versus aging out.  Of course it's just one of a number of factors, so it's never a guarantee.

Answer (score 3):

> Would it ever be seen without this meta question, or would it also have been a wasted flag?

Close Flags are handled by the Close Votes review queue, [which at the moment is very large](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats). There aren't enough reviewers to handle everything pushed into the queue, so a large portion of close flags are not being handled.

If your flag ages away, you have a few options:

- If you still think it needs to be closed, you can reflag it (this is possible after your flag ages away).
- We have a chat room called [Stack Overflow Close Votes Reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) that can handle your request to close the question. Be sure to read [the tour](https://socvr.org/tour) before posting, and only post your request if it *really* needs to be closed.
- You can start a discussion on meta.

Comment: You call under 6k "very large"? Man, last time I checked, the close vote queue was around 10k. We are actually making progress.

Comment: @CodyGray I definitely agree it's better than it was a week ago; however, 6000 is still a *lot* of posts to review. We're definitely making progress, but Close Votes still ain't small.

Comment: You took it a bit too seriously. It was more of a "back in my day, we had to walk uphill both ways" comment. Perhaps you will get used to my sense of humor some day. Yes, it's an absurd number of posts to review. We need a better system, or at least a more efficient way of dispatching the posts that do exist.

Comment: @CodyGray The number next to the queue is effectively meaningless.  The number is based entirely on how items age out of the queue.  If you want to measure the number of flags not evaluated by the review queue you need to count the rate that flags aging away (perhaps also as a portion of flags actually evaluated).  The number that haven't yet aged away is in no way an indication of how likely a flag is to actually get evaluated when cast.  The fact that "back in the day" the number was bigger doesn't actually impact what matters, the number of posts reviewed.

Comment: I agree, @Servy; I still think that aging away closure flags is a misfeature. At the very least, it sweeps the problem under the rug, instead of dealing with it. We need to find a way to deal with this at scale. The only thing I’d say is that the ~10k number comes from only a few months ago, when aging away was already being done, and I’m not aware of any recent tweaks to the algorithm that would cause more votes to be aging away faster messing with the stats.

Comment: @CodyGray The point is that the size of the queue is not a function of how many items are being processed, it's a function of how many are being flagged and the aging algorithm.  The only way that the size is ever affected by how many are being processed is when they're processed faster than they're coming in, at which point the queue will reach 0 (if that is sustained) in the amount of time it takes a single flag to age out, and I...doubt that's happening right now.  So the point is that the queue size isn't indicating what it's being claimed to indicate.